# How to write "concave" equals sign in latex

Tags: fractions

I am reading a mathematical paper and they use this concave looking equals sign:

[image: Concave looking equals sign]

I was unable to find how to write this in LaTeX. I don't even know what this sign is called. They use it to denote that the fraction of the two quantities is bounded from below and above by real constants. Does anyone know how to write it in LaTex?

Comment: This is not a mathematical question. In principle, it should be posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/), but if you do that, then your question will be closed as a duplicate of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/134805).

Comment: I am tempted to replace the image with $$\Large R_n\asymp a_n$$